# How to get report showing Java classes bigger than 500 lines? (And publish on Jenkins)

Tags: java, jenkins, static-code-analysis

I have got legacy project with a lot of too big classes.
I need to present that as report to manager to start cleaning-up and refactoring.
I already have [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) job for this project with [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) maven goal configured:

> pmd:pmd

I am researching on:

How to get list of Java classes (and JavaScript, HTML files ...) longer that 500 lines?

How to get list of Java classes with functions longer that 50 lines?

And it would be perfect to have that publish on Jenkins, i.e. as a report.
However any simple solution would do. For example: 
plain listing as full class name, LOC (lines of code). Sorted by LOC descending.

Simple Format

```
Name LOC
com.example.HugeClass 5000
com.example.BigClass  3540
com.example.BigClass2 3390
```

Comment: The number of lines in a class file or the number of lines you write in a day is a poor indicator of the quality of code (or much else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html), or use [SONAR](http://www.sonarsource.org/), which aggregates Checkstyle, PMD, Findbugs and other checks and generates reports and more.

Comment: How to get that with Checkstyle?

Comment: And this is exactly what needed. (See right column http://nemo.sonarsource.org/drilldown/measures/241720?metric=lines)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tools. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java
You need to pick one and find out how configure it.